# Exposing a Web Service from WSDL instead of XSD in Spring WebService

Tags: java, spring-ws

In our project we are using Spring WebService. The configuration file is like below:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfiguration extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        PayloadValidatingInterceptor validatingInterceptor = new PayloadValidatingInterceptor();
        validatingInterceptor.setValidateRequest(true);
        validatingInterceptor.setValidateResponse(true);
        validatingInterceptor.setXsdSchema(customerSchema());
        interceptors.add(validatingInterceptor);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/abc/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "someInterface")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema priceListSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("SomePortType");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/abc/ws/someInterface");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("someNamespace");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(priceListSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema customerSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("SomeXsd.xsd"));
    }
}
```

The XSD file of the wsdl is SomeXsd.xsd whixh we have kept in the classpath. But I want to know if I have the wsdl file that will be exposed instead of generating the wsdl in this way. How we can expose an wsdl that is already present?

Comment: Did you try SimpleWsdl11Definition ?

Comment: No, can you kindly elaborate on that?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try removing the following

```
   @Bean(name = "someInterface")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema priceListSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("SomePortType");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/abc/ws/someInterface");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("someNamespace");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(priceListSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }
```

and adding this

```
 @Bean
    public WsdlDefinition myWsdl() {
        return new SimpleWsdl11Definition(new ClassPathResource("/myWsdl.wsdl"));
    }
```

You will still need the xsd for the validator. You might need more configuration also

Comment: I only have the wsdl and nothing else. If I still need to specify the xsd which is inline to the wsdl, I will still have to do rework, extract the xsd from inside the wsdl, make a new xsd file, store it in my classpath and then specify that inside the code.

Comment: This is somewhat tough than jaxws where I only need to generate the implementing classes from the wsdl and can work on them for contract first webservice development.

Comment: I agree and I tried to use the import function in the wsdl (in order to not duplicate the xsd) but the displayed wsdl has the "import xsd" rather than the xsd inline.... so I ended up with two xsd to maintain....

Comment: Yes that is the problem